# Unable to get PID on a Listening port for Solaris

Tags: process, solaris, telnet, port

I'm using solaris

```
SunOS myhost4 5.11 11.4.42.117.3 sun4v sparc sun4v non-global-zone
```

I'm sure that port 7777 is in use as the telnet is successful as below:

```
$ telnet myhost4 7777
Trying 10.23.52.219...
Connected to myhost4.mybank.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

The below script works and gives me the PID for most of the ports

cat getpidfromport.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# $1 is the port we are looking for

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
echo "Please provide a port number parameter for this script"
echo "e.g. $0 1521"
exit
fi

echo "Greping for your port, please be patient (CTRL+C breaks)..."

for i in `ls /proc`
do
pfiles $i 2>/dev/null | grep AF_INET | grep -w $1
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo Is owned by pid $i
echo ----
fi
done
```

However, when i pass the port 7777 it does not give me the pid using that port

```
./getpidfromport.sh 7777
No results found!!
```

Can you please suggest how can i get the pid using port 7777?

Answer (score 0):

For those kind of scripts you need to access `/proc` filesystem which can be done by `root` user. Try:

```
sudo ./getpidfromport.sh 7777
```

Comment: This is not a permission issue as the same script works and gets me the pid for port 22 and others. Also, i need a non-root solution please.

Comment: @Ashar, you can see port 22 because you did `ssh` to the machine. If you need to see ports/pids you are not owner you need `root`